# How to optimize and speed up this operation

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers("ACT");
Foreach(var customer in customers)
{
  SaveCustomerData (customer);
}
```

Now in this operation - I get a list of customers object, which could be in thousands then save each customer object in database, one by one.
Is there a way I could speed up or make it parallel in someway to really achieve performance and right result.

Comment: I suggest that you look into the async and await keywords. what you want is an array of tasks or actions that you wait to complete before starting more. You're trying to multithread your application and that *requires* an understanding of the issues assoiated with it such as race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers("ACT");
Task[] tasks = new Task[MaxNumOfConcurrentSaves];
While(customers.Length > 0)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < MaxNumOfConcurrentTasks; i++){
            tasks[i] = SaveCustomerData(customers[i]);
            customers[i] = null;
     }
     customers = List.FindAll<Customer>(customers, aCust => !(aCust == null));
     Task.AwaitAll(tasks)
}
```

Ok so here's whats happening (and you'll have to perfect it for your uses): while we have customers in the list, for every one of them starting at the begining through to the max number of concurrent tasks, start the task to save and set that customer to null. then, after the for loop is over, find all the customer entries in the list that aren't null and keep them and await the tasks to complete. if there's nothing left in the list then the loop is over and the save process is complete. SaveCustomerData would return a task that executes he actual save code.

If any one sees issues with this code please edit or bring it to my attention. I have not tested it in this capacity but it is similar to something I've done that works.

Edit:

I have recently found something amazing for this task in .Net 4.5 (maybe 4 too, not sure)

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers("ACT");
Parallel.ForEach(customers, (currentCustomer) => SaveCustomerData(currentCustomer))
```

Same thing, Multithreaded in one line.

Comment: If this helped solve your problem, please mark it as the selected answer. If it didn't, please create one and then mark it.

Comment: Marked so. Thanks. Another question around the Task.AwaitAll() would be, how do i catch exception and log specific with customer number.    i could put a try catch around Task.AwaitAll() ?

Comment: Do that in the save function. make a logging opject the utilizes File.Append(), and log those to two files: one for that specific customer save run, and one for all failed customers. Alternatively use the console if available.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure which takes many customers as a parameter.  Call this procedure once with all your customers. One network hit.

Comment: Sure one time on the network. But I wonder how many bytes a single customer object takes up? That could end being gigabytes over the network at once. you'd be worse off in that case.

Comment: I hope someone with tens of millions of customers is not using stack overflow to find out how to update all their customers in one hit!.I also hope that do not have all of those millions of customers in memory at one time, update them, write them to the database and complain that it takes a long time)

Comment: Yes I do as well - though that still depends on size of the customers memory footprint.  This also doesn't achieve the OP's goal. Now you're relying on, for example, the database server to handle the task instead.